# Displaying UnSplash image URL's on Processing Sketch

Tags: processing

I am trying to display a random image URL retrieved via the UnSplash API on a processing screen.  There are two issues I think: 1) the url delivered does not have a supported extension such as .jpg etc. It looks like this for example:

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672710509828-c971003d3533?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=Mnw0MDM3NDd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ5MzI4OTM&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=400

I also imagine that an issue might be that the image is not local?

Can anyone help me with this?
Tracy

```
PImage IMG;

void setup () {

  size(1000, 1000);
  background (255);

  IMG = loadImage("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672710509828-c971003d3533?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=Mnw0MDM3NDd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ5MzI4OTM&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=400");
}

void draw() {
  image(IMG, 0, 0);
}
```

I get an error saying cannot load because it does not have a typical image extension.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to add your own URL encoded variable with the sole purpose of ending the URL with ".jpg"

Here's a basic example:

```java
PImage img;

void setup(){
  size(400, 600);
  noLoop();
  String originalURL = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1672710509828-c971003d3533?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=Mnw0MDM3NDd8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2NzQ5MzI4OTM&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=80&w=400";
  img = loadImage(originalURL + "&p5=image.jpg");
}

void draw(){
  image(img, 0, 0);
}
```